# Sudoers: can't run two command lists where the second has a glob * and denies the first

Tags: sudo

What I want is:

- to be able to run `/sbin/print/managequeue.sh -p app1 --view` as
  another user without asking for a password.
- to be able to run `/sbin/print/managequeue.sh -p app1 --cancel`
  (or `--delete`, or    `--pause`, etc) as another user, but asking for
  password.

Preferably, I don't want to create a `Cmnd_Alias` with all possible arguments. So, I tried the three aliases and the User Specification below:

```
Host_Alias      PRINTSRVS = printsrv, printsrvbkp
Cmnd_Alias      APP1PMV = /sbin/print/managequeue.sh -p app1 --view
Cmnd_Alias      APP1PMD = /sbin/print/managequeue.sh -p app1 *, !APP1PMV

%app1adms, %helpdesk PRINTSRVS = (printop2:printop2) NOPASSWD: APP1PMV, \
                                 (printop2:printop2) PASSWD: APP1PMD
```

When I run `sudo -u printop2 /sbin/print/managequeue.sh -p app1 --cancel` it works:

```
[sudo] password for app1adm1:
Managing queue...
```

But when I run `sudo -u printop2 /sbin/print/managequeue.sh -p app1 --view` it doesn't:

```
Sorry, user app1adm1 is not allowed to execute '/sbin/print/managequeue.sh -p app1 --view' as printop2 on printsrv.
```

Apparently my second command `(printop2:printop2) PASSWD: APP1PMD` overrode my first command `(printop2:printop2) NOPASSWD: APP1PMV` and denied the `--view` argument altogether.

Would you please explain this issue?

Comment: I can't test right now, but I believe order matters and sudo reads bottom-up; try swapping the order of the commands

Comment: I made some tests and it seems order really matters and it´s top-down. Apparently if two commands are conflicting the one on the bottom is kept. In sudores File format section it says: When multiple entries match for a user, they are applied in order.  _Where there are multiple matches, the last match is used (which is not necessarily the most specific match)._

Comment: Feel free to self-answer!

Comment: if you can post as an answer I flag as answered. You led me to find it.

Comment: In the future, keep in mind U&L policy (and likely other sites’) against cross-posting/ multi-posting. It’s seen as a waste of multiple people’s attention and may result in votes to close one or all of the posts. It’s one of many StackExchange‘s inner workings. Thank you, and welcome to the network!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [sudoers (v1.8.25) description](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.25/sudoers.man.html):

> When multiple entries match for a user, they are applied in order. Where there are multiple matches, the last match is used (which is not necessarily the most specific match).

... you'll need to swap the order around so that the `--view` version of the command is listed last.